# Export to excel functionality on JQuery dialoge buttons - MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Jquery dialoge box which contains 4 buttons . Export to excel is one of them.
I am trying to export my grid data to excel . Please let me know if you have any similar examples.

Please let me know , how should i write and call export to excel on jquery dialog button click.

Answer (score 0):

To write something to excel file:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;

//top of document
workSheet.Cells[1, 1] = string.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
workSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Something1";
workSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "Something2";
workSheet.Cells[4, 3] = "Something3";
workSheet.Cells[6, 3] = "Something4";

// test content
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   workSheet.Cells[i + 9, 1] = (i + 1).ToString(); 
   workSheet.Cells[i + 9, 2] = i.ToString();
   workSheet.Cells[i + 9, 3] = Math.Round(2.555, 2);
   workSheet.Cells[i + 9, 4] = "Hi"; 
   workSheet.Cells[i + 9, 5] = i.ToString();
   workSheet.Cells[i + 9, 6] = i.ToString();         
}

//show document
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

When "Export to excell" button clicks, call a action that contains above code.